# I'm trying to create a drawing app with javascript, but the canvas element it's supposed to take place in is unresponsive. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is supposed to be a javascript drawing application within the site. Users should be able to simply load the site and be able to draw within the canvas. Right now, the canvas is unresponsive despite a lack of error messages... anybody see anything wrong? I might just be too new to this.

```js
// paint.js
(function () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //resizing
  //canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  //canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

  //variables
  var painting = false;

  function startPosition(e) {
    painting = true;
    draw(e);
  }

  function endPosition() {
    painting = false;
    context.beginPath();
  }

  function draw(e) {
    if (!painting) return;
    context.lineWidth = 7;
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.strokeStyle = "green";

    context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    context.stroke();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }

  //EventListeners
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", endPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
})();
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    text-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
    background: #e0ebdd;
    font-family: helvetica;
}

.nav {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", "monospace";
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
}

.nav a {
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color:#FFB52A;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.footer {
    clear: both;
}

.info {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    text-size: 16px;
}

.wavingHand {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    clear: right;
    width: 100px; 
    padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>draw-and-listen</title>
<link href="grove.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<h1>draw and listen</h1>

<div class="nav">
    
        <a href="artists.html">artists</a>
        <a href="draw-and-listen.html">draw and listen</a>
        <a href="store.html">store</a>

</div>
    
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="480" width="640" style="border:1px solid #000000; background-color: white;">Please update your browser.</canvas>
  <script src="paint.js"></script> 
</div>

<a class="aHome" href="index.html"><img src="img/planet-green.png" style="float:right;width:42px;height:42px;" alt="home planet"></a>

<div>

    <p style="clear: right;">© 2020</p>
    
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Oddly enough, when I run it in here, it seems to work (although the mouse is misaligned...) but when I simply run the HTML in google chrome, the canvas is unresponsive.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet?

Comment: There should be code in the question. There is on my end.

Comment: Can you not see it?

Comment: I meant if you can add a snippet so we can run the code and see the output.

Comment: Yes, I can see it, but I can't run it.

Comment: Shoot, how do I make it so you can?

Comment: Click the `</>` button and paste in your code.

Comment: Alright done. Unfortunately, it works in here but doesn't when I run the HTML in chrome to test it...

Comment: Alright, actually it works. But only when the window is not fullscreen...

Answer (score 1):

In fact, your code is working, you can log something in the `draw` function. The problem is the (X,Y) coordination. In your case, you can set both of canvas viewport size and canvas element size to same value to ensure the incorrect mouse position.

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="480" width="640" style="border:1px solid #000000; width: 640px; height:480px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: This makes sense, but still, I find that the mouse position is still off, and still only works when the window is small...